# Are there jewish holidays that are like sabbaths?

Tags: shabbat

A friend of mine told me that today was a [High Sabbath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Sabbaths). However, this does not appear to be a recognized term.

As far as I know, a High Sabbath is like Shabbat (with all the precepts and restrictions placed on that day), but it does not necessarily take place on that day.

Unfortunately, this is all I know, so I was wondering if there is indeed a holiday/observance of any sort that is along these lines.

As an alternative route to achieving the answer: What, if any, religious observances are taking place today (April 19th 2017)?

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with the term "High Sabbath" and based on the linked Wikipedia article, this appears to be a term primarily used by Christians and "Messianic Jews" (a.k.a. Christians).

On various of the Jewish festivals, many of the precepts and restrictions of Shabbat are applied on some or all of the festival days. This includes holidays such as [Passover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover), [Shavuot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavuot), [Rosh Hashanah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_Hashanah), [Sukkot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukkot), and some others. Some of these holidays are referred to metaphorically as "Shabbat" in the Torah.

While *most* of the restrictions on work that apply to Shabbat are also applied on these days, there are some exceptions such as cooking. The only holiday on which *all* of the Shabbat restrictions are in effect (plus some others as well) is [Yom Kippur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Kippur).

19 April 2017 was not a holiday on the Jewish calendar; however, it was the day after the 8th day of Passover which is celebrated in the [diaspora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_diaspora) and is one of the days when many of the Shabbat restrictions are in place. It seems likely that Passover is what your friend was referring to.

Edit:

There is some debate among the *halakhic* authorities about where on earth the date line should be for the purposes of Jewish law. I am far from an expert on this, but I believe there are a few varying opinions about when to observe Shabbat and holidays in certain places within and on the western side of the Pacific Ocean. In particular, I think there are at least some opinions that some locations should celebrate Shabbat on Sunday. According to those opinions, it may be that April 19 was itself the 8th day of Passover. If your friend lives in Hawaii, Samoa, or Japan this may be the case. I don't know what any of those places do in practice, so I can't say for sure that this is even a possibility but it's possible that it's a possibility so hey at least there's that.

Comment: Very unlikely that this is what was referred to, but [Mimouna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimouna) was celebrated in certain communities outside of Israel on April 19th this year.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Cool! I've never heard of that! Although I agree that it seems unlikely that this is what the friend was referring to as I don't see any mention of _issur melacha_ in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: see my answer for a theory that the supposed "high sabbath" [a Christian misunderstanding of "second first sabbath" in the Gospel of Luke] is actually the sabbath following the first sabbath during the week of Pesach.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research on this as it came up on the Biblical HermeneuticsSE. It does seem that the High Sabbath or "Second Sabbath" is a Christian concept, based on a passage from the Gospel of Luke, which refers to Jesus's disciples gleaning grain on the "second first sabbath" (in Greek but not usually translated literally). This term is understood by some to mean a "second sabbath" or "high sabbath," as mentioned in @Daniel's answer. The real meaning, according to [this article](https://ronconte.com/2011/01/13/what-is-the-second-first-sabbath-luke-61/) relates to the "first sabbath after Pesach."

> The second first Sabbath is the first Sabbath after the first Sabbath
> of Passover. The first Sabbath of Passover is used as a starting point
> for counting the seven weeks (and seven Sabbaths) until the Feast of
> Weeks. The day after the first Sabbath of Passover is day one in that
> count... [There is also] the first Sabbath in the count of seven
> Sabbaths to the Feast of Weeks (which is held on the day after that
> 7th Sabbath, i.e. the fiftieth day, or Pentecost). So there are two
> first Sabbaths: the first Sabbath during Passover... and the first Sabbath after Passover, which is
> the second first Sabbath.

**If anyone can confirm this or refute it, I'd like get back the BHSE people and let them know.**

Answer (score 0):

On regular Sabbath you can't weave, nor bake food. On most holidays you can bake food but not weave. Yom Kippur is described as a "Sabbath of Sabbaths" as it's a holiday but follows the extra restrictions (no cooking), and what's more adds the restrictions on eating as well. That's all.

Comment: Do you have a source that issurei ochel nefesh is learned from Shabbat Shabbaton?